# What is plugin in phonegap and How to use it?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am New In Phonegap and i confuse about phonegap plugin and how to use it plugin in android ?

Any one know about this...thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A PhoneGap/Cordova plugin bridges a bit of functionality between the WebView
>   powering a PhoneGap/Cordova application and the native platform the PhoneGap/Cordova
>   application is running on. Plugins are composed of a single JavaScript
>   interface used across all platforms, and native implementations
>   following platform-specific Plugin interfaces that the JavaScript will
>   call into. It should be noted that all of the core PhoneGap/Cordova APIs are
>   implemented using this exact architecture.

For more information take a look at the [plugin development guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) and our [repository of plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins).

Comment: can we develop owen plugin depend our requirment

Answer (score 0):

A Plugin is a piece of Software that does something the out-of-the-box phonegap implementation can´t do.

- Written in javascript (makes use of phonegap`s exec function) **and** native code, so a plugin is always platform-specifiic
- Usually plugins have their own documentation of how to use them. In android you usually add one or more `.java` files to your `src` folder, `.jar` archives, which you add into your `libs` folder (and add it to build-path - in eclipse or in terminal via `abd-update-project`) and a `.js` File to your `/assets/www` folder. this javascript file also contains the api for the plugin.
- Sometimes plugins consist of whole java-libraries or need own activities, so sometimes to use a plugin you have to make changes in your `manifest.xml`.

A list of android plugins can be found on [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android)